# enhanced ecommerce conversion issues

Tags: google-analytics

This is the code being sent from our confirmation page for GA universal using enhanced ecommerce:

```
ga("create", "UA-XXXXXXX-xx", "auto");
ga("require", "displayfeatures");
ga("require", "ec");
ga("ec:addProduct", {
    Id: null, 
    Name: "ProductNameTest", 
    Brand: "Foo", 
    Category: null, 
    Variant: null, 
    Price: 5.49, 
    Quantity: 1, 
    Coupon: "", 
    Position: 0
});
ga("ec:setAction", "purchase", {
    Id: "33558", 
    Affiliation: "Foo", 
    Revenue: 5.49, 
    Tax: 0, 
    Shipping: 0, 
    Coupon: "", 
    List: null, 
    Step: 4, 
    Option: null
});
ga("send", "pageview");
```

I'm not seeing any issues in the GA debugger or in the Tag Assistant plugin for Chrome.

What am I missing here that our conversion data/transactions aren't showing up?

EDIT:

Here is the output from the GA debugger that I stripped for the above:

```
Initializing Google Analytics.
Loading resource for plugin: ec
Loading script: "http://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/ec.js"
Running command: ga("create", "UA-XXXXXXX-xx", "auto")
Creating new tracker: t0
Running command: ga("require", "displayfeatures")
Set called on unknown field: "dcLoaded".
Plugin "displayfeatures" intialized on tracker "t0".
Running command: ga("require", "ec")
Waiting on require of "ec" to be fulfilled.
Executing Google Analytics commands.
Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "ec", Function)
Running command: ga("require", "ec")
Plugin "ec" intialized on tracker "t0".
Running command: ga("send", "pageview")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a few issues that could be affecting your transactions:

1. Duplicate `ga("require", "ec")` commands.
2. `Id` for `addProduct` is null. This is a [required value](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product-data), and should be a string.
3. More of a javascript best practice: after you've invoked your function, end it with a semicolon. e.g. `ga("send", "pageview");`

**EDIT:**
Regarding point #2, the `Id` for `addProduct` CAN be null, if the developer is passing a value for the name parameter instead (see [Product Data table](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product-data)).

All property key's must be lowercase i.e. `Id` should be `id`. (Thanks for Eduardo for pointing out).

Comment: Good Answer I'd also add the fact that all parameters are capitilized. It should be "id" not "Id"

Comment: I copied this output from the GA debugger. I just forgot to put semicolons here. For the id, it is followed by a star on the documentation. 'The product ID or SKU (e.g. P67890). *Either this field or name must be set. The name of the product (e.g. Android T-Shirt). *Either this field or id must be set.'

Comment: @NexAddo, check-out Eduardo's comment: all parameters are capitalized i.e. 'Id' should be 'id'.

Comment: @Blexy Thanks, just fixed that and tested a couple transactions. They show up now!